# Firebase not connecting to iOS app even though google info plist file attached

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, dart

My flutter app is crashing when I connect it to firebase and try to use it. It is only happening for this app(other apps are connecting fine). I am not sure why? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.I followed several tutorials and all of them did the same.

I have registered the app :

- Provided bundle identifier
- Attached the info-plist file

Flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed
instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
flutter config --android-sdk to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Flutter run :
Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        30.6s
Xcode build done.                                           76.0s
Lost connection to device.
Activating Dart DevTools...                                         4.0s

Answer (score 0):

looks like you haven't installed flutter correctly.
check https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

Comment: I have, thats why the default app is working perfectly